# Value of type '1-dimensional array of byte' cannot be converted to a byte

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to pass values to a backgroundworker. I previously posted to ask how it could be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27555467/passing-values-to-and-from-background-worker/27557931#27557931). An answer directed me to this code, but I'm having issues trying to use it. Here's what I'm doing:

```
Class MyParameters
    Friend strInputFile As String
    Friend strOutputFile As String
    Friend bytKey As Byte
    Friend bytIV As Byte
    Friend Direction As New CryptoAction
End Class
```

.

```
Private Sub bnEcrypt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnEcrypt.Click
        Dim bytKey As Byte()
        Dim bytIV As Byte()


        'Send the password to the CreateKey function.
        bytKey = CreateKey(txtPass.Text)
        'Send the password to the CreateIV function.
        bytIV = CreateIV(txtPass.Text)

        Dim m As New MyParameters
        m.strInputFile = txtFile.Text
        m.strOutputFile = txtPlaceIn.Text
        m.bytKey = bytKey
        m.bytIV = bytIV
        m.Direction = CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt
```

But I'm getting a error: **Value of type '1-dimensional array of byte' cannot be converted to a byte'**. on these two:

```
        m.bytKey = bytKey
        m.bytIV = bytIV
```

Any help?

Comment: Remove `m.bytKey = bytKey` and `m.bytIV = bytIV` or change `Friend bytKey As Byte` and `Friend bytIV As Byte` to `Friend ... AS Byte()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your variables defined as a `Byte` instead of a byte array `Byte()`.

Use this:

```
Friend bytKey As Byte()
Friend bytIV As Byte()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class needs to accept a `Byte()` instead:

```
Class MyParameters
    Friend strInputFile As String
    Friend strOutputFile As String
    Friend bytKey As Byte() ' <-- Changed from Byte
    Friend bytIV As Byte() ' <-- Changed from Byte
    Friend Direction As New CryptoAction
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared two byte fields in the class. Declare two arrays instead:

```
Friend bytKey() As Byte
Friend bytIV() As Byte
```